# How to set order AND seasonal params for SARIMA

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, statsmodels, arima

Hi can someone give me a dummy guide for setting the order params and seasonal order params in the SARIMA model from statsmodels?

Are those numbers obtained from the ACF and PACF plot? If yes, how do you get the numbers for AR and MA from those plots? I know the differencing(I) cannot be derived from those two plots, how should I decide whether I should set it to 0, 1, or 2?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
pip install pmdarima
```

[pmdarima](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima)

```
pip install pyramid-arima
```

Please look at:
[pyramid-auto-arima](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/modules/generated/pyramid.arima.auto_arima.html#pyramid-arima-auto-arima)

```
from pyramid.arima.stationarity import ADFTest
adf_test = ADFTest(alpha=0.05)
adf_test.is_stationary(series)
train, test = series[1:500], series[501:910]
train.shape
test.shape
plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(test)
plt.title("Pyramid")
plt.show()
```

It does:

```
arima_fit =  statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX(data_set, order = (1,0,1), seasonal_order = (0,1,0,50), trend = 'c').fit() 
prediction = arima_fit.predict('start', 'end', dynamic = True)
```

About your question regarding to ACF and PACF

> The ACF stands for Autocorrelation function, and the PACF for Partial
>   Autocorrelation function. Looking at these two plots together can help
>   us form an idea of what models to fit. Autocorrelation computes and
>   plots the autocorrelations of a time series. Autocorrelation is the
>   correlation between observations of a time series separated by k time
>   units.
>
> Similarly, partial autocorrelations measure the strength of
>   relationship with other terms being accounted for, in this case other
>   terms being the intervening lags present in the model. For example,
>   the partial autocorrelaton at lag 4 is the correlation at lag 4,
>   accounting for the correlations at lags 1, 2, and 3. To generate these
>   plots in Minitab, we go to Stat > Time Series > Autocorrelation or
>   Stat > Time Series > Partial Autocorrelation. I've generated these
>   plots for our simulated data below:

[image]

[Fitting-an-arima-model](https://blog.minitab.com/blog/starting-out-with-statistical-software/fitting-an-arima-model)

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much.

Comment: @EdwardLam You are most welcome, this link is also from a to z about arima and etc: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs3750/lectures/class16.pdf